# Appropriate Statistical Test to Determine Internal Cohesion of a Categorical Data

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, item-response-theory

I have a dataset that is composed of mainly binary variables, each row represents a patient, and each column represents a symptom of a disease. The patient would tick 1 (if they experience the symptoms) and zero otherwise. Each table represents a disease, which looks like:

Table 1. Disease A Only

| Symptom 1 | Symptom 2 | ...... | Symptom N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | .... | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | .... | 1 |
| .... | .... | .... | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | ... | 1 |

I wanted to perform a test to determine if the patients came from the same population, that is there is minimum variation in their responses. Ideally the notion that patients should share the same symptoms for a specific disease should be true since a disease usually manifest itself in a form of symptom, however in reality this is not the case as some may experience it while others do not.

I am looking for a statistical test to show that the patient responses are coherent (the responses are homogenous), which indicates that almost all share the same symptoms, if the patient responses are incoherent, then it warrants another investigation as to why.

I have read about phi coefficient but it is only good for two binary variable, further reading have led me to chi-square test, and multi-correspondence analysis, unfortunately, I am confused which of the two are the most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

A latent class analysis approach might work here. You are proposing that there is a single class, where each patient has the same symptoms, and variation is noise - not two (or more) distinct classes.

You can test whether one, two or more classes are a better match to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two analysis you mention, the $\chi^2$ test and multiple correspondence analysis (MCA), I would say the former is the better choice since you are interested in formally testing the extent to which symptoms co occur in the population of interest.

MCA is a data analysis technique used for categorical data, often in survey research. It's an extension of correspondence analysis (CA) which is used for two-way tables. MCA allows for the **visualization** of the relationships between several categorical variables (such as symptoms) and the individuals. It can be a good choice for exploring patterns in your data, but it's more of an exploratory tool rather than a confirmatory one. It helps in visualizing the data and understanding underlying patterns but does not provide a specific test statistic for hypothesis testing. This is all to say that MCA may be useful to explore the data, but not to make formal statistical inference.

The $\chi^2$ test on the other hand is used to determine if there is a significant association between two categorical variables. In your case, you can apply it to pairs of symptoms to see if the presence of one symptom is associated with the presence of another. However, the limitation here is that it only examines two variables at a time. To analyze all symptoms together, you would need to conduct multiple chi-square tests, which increases the complexity and risk of Type I errors (i.e., false positives).